# Start web application automatically on log-in

Tags: chromium, autostart, webapps

This question has two components:

- Make a website like Outlook 365 into an app. (One approach I describe below is to use Google Chrome / Chromium)
- Open that app automatically on log-in. This is the tricky bit, and is the reason I'm asking.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to get email and calendar notifications without needing to remember to browse to Outlook 365.

So far, I've used Chromium to put the app onto my Desktop folder. But I'm having trouble getting it to start automatically. I've added the following command into `Startup Applications`: `cd ~/Desktop; gtk-launch chrome-mfelnnlfnkpgnoponopclbnbogfgjmje-Default`. But the app doesn't start when I log in.

[edit]

This question is not a straightforward duplicate of [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login), because the GUI based approaches don't work in this case. The non-GUI based approach described in one of the answers does.

Comment: If one of the answers to the linked question solved your problem then your is a duplicate of said question.

Comment: @DavidFoerster You've been here longer than me, so I ultimately defer to your and your peers' judgement. But none of the answers to that question helped, apart from a small and easily overlooked part of one. I know that because I'd read the linked question before asking mine. Hence, I think my answer could help someone. I don't think this question should be closed because I think it could benefit from other answers -- the non-GUI based approach could make administration more complicated. Again, just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your well stated and worthwhile opinion even if I disagree with it. Imho that's a sign that we should make the relevant answer section more visible though in this case I believe it's visible enough considering that the GUI method will be enough for most people. Everybody who finds your question will still see the reference to the linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed one of the options given in the top answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login), the one where it says "Non GUI approach". I moved the Chromium web app to `~/.config/autostart`, and it works now.